# Why stellar required XLM to activate account

Tags: stellar-core, stellar-sdk, stellar.toml

I am using stellar for custom token. And each time a customer creating a account on stellar they required 1 XLM to activate there account.

We are using custom coins only so why should be activate account using XML ?

Is there any way to manage all customers account using a single private key ?

Stellar federated server is a bit confusing for me.

Answer (score 1):

> We are using custom coins only so why should be activate account using XML?

The network need to lock base reserve and charge minimum transaction fees to prevent transactions spamming by bad actors. It's essential because all transactions end up in history archives and operational databases, resulting in significant blockchain size increase. Validators have to pay more for storage and move costly servers in order to handle ever increasing blockchain.

> Is there any way to manage all customers account using a single private key?

You can track all your customers internally, [in your database](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/anchor/index.html). It requires additional coding and database maintenance, however this approach allows you to use single Stellar account for all deposits and withdrawals.

Comment: What about Stellar Federation Server ? Can i use this to manage multiple user account ? I just want to remove paying 1 XLM by customer.

Comment: Federation server is optional. Transaction memo is all you need. Check this guide: https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/exchange.html

Comment: How can i manage all users account using memo ? Should i need to create a database for users and user balance and all trancations ?